# How to replace string with the icon in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am trying to make ViewPager with TabLayout and use icons instead of text in TabLayout. I tried tutorials, answers on stackoverflow, but nothing helped to solve my problem.

**My TabLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                local:theme="@style/ViewPagerTheme"
                />
```

**MyCustomTabLayout Style**

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>

</style>

<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

**My PagerAdapter getPageTitle()**

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(App.getContext(), PageInfo.getByPosition(position).getIConResId());
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}
```

I am using a style with set

`<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>`

but when I change `SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");` 
to something like this

`SpannableString sb = new SpannableString("a");`

my TabLayout reflects with caps A and if leave blank space my TabLayout have no value and is blank, I guess problem should be in this step but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If you are trying to use images instead of text, why are you setting the text of the tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
  tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly when I removed "public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) " function

Answer (score 0):

you can set icon instead of string in tab layout, For this use following line of code.

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example try once https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByZqApcbZkTqcUtxaXlfU3FETjg